# I want to know the mix rgb source code

Tags: shaders

I downloaded the source code, but I don't know where it is.
I want to know how it works by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source code here:
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_mixRgb.c

Comment: there is no script. for example mix a * a = b

Comment: @supermoon .. maybe that should be an answer in its own right. ( You can answer your own question)

Comment: If you want the actual equations, see [ramp_blend](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/5cf6f570c65daa3325055e54bb07fa864f269960/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/material.c#L1395).